# add TAB InfoBubble in EXT JS 4

Tags: google-maps, extjs, extjs4, infobubble

i have a problem in EXT JS, when add infobubble tab the tab become Vertical align,i want become original Horizontal align, i think is the EXT JS CSS problem, have any idea to modify it?

```
This is the example
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anthor/vgxaV/3/

**this is original Infobubble**

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fiddle works in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ach7N/6/

The issue is with the following extjs css rule:

```
.x-border-box, .x-border-box * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I added reset-box-sizing class to your center panel and the following css:

```
.x-border-box .reset-box-sizing * {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Done with  `-moz-box-sizing: content-box;`